# Webmaster tool validation for JSON + ld structured data

Tags: asp.net, json, google-analytics, google-search-console, rich-snippets

I am using Structured Data Markup for a product page. And using json + ld and have put the script tags in the header section.

[image]

The script section is marked by two lines. And when I validate the JSON segment in http://json-ld.org/playground/index.html   it gives a proper output. But when I validate it with Google webmaster tools it does not show me the content.
http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets

Kindly help me in identifying any issue with this. I think I have made this correctly.

For More Info , I am posting the JSON segment with this.

```
<script type="application/ld+json"> {
"@context": "http://schema.org",
"@type": "Product",
"productID": "mpn:20AV002YMB",
"description": "Whether you re an overachiever or an up-and-comer, ThinkPad laptops are the tools you need. From the thin-and-light wonder to the heavy-duty mobile workstation, they re built, tested and enhanced for reliability, durability and speed. Enjoy superior web conferencing on your L540, which includes a low-light sensitive 720p HD webcam with wide-angle viewing.",
"url": "http://www.abc.lk/lenovo/business-notebook/thinkpad-l540-core-i5-4200m-4gb-500gb-15-6in-1080p-dvdrw-win7-pro-win8-pro-azb/20av002ymb/product-details/m852r253.aspx",
"name": "ThinkPad L540 Core i5-4200m / 4GB 500GB 15.6in 1080p Dvdrw Win7 Pro / Win8 Pro Azb",
"image": "https://www.abc.lk/ProductImages/images/M852R253.jpg",
"model": "ThinkPad   L540",
"manufacturer": { 
"name": "Lenovo",
"url": "http://www.abc.lk/en/lenovo"
 }, 
"offers": { 
"@type": "Offer",
"availability": "http://schema.org/OutOfStock",
"price": "706.97",
"priceCurrency": "EUR"
 } 
}
</script>
```

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Webmaster Tools does not support JSON-LD (at time of writing) However Google Search does.

You can see this thread for more information:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/9lzzOw2W-dk

and use Google's beta markup tester for email:

https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/ (which will also work for web HTML) - Your JSON validates here

I know this is an old thread, but I thought it might be useful for anyone searching for answers to this who lands here.

Answer (score 0):

Now Google has created a utility that will detect RDFa and JSON-LD (maybe Microdata too, Haven't tried.)

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/structured-data/testing-tool/